# NewLanguageFeatures-lambda expression use n importance

Tags: c#, lambda

I was going through the concepts of lambda expression & extension methods :-

```
namespace NewLanguageFeatures
{ 
public delegate bool KeyValuePair<K, V>(K key, V value);  
/// <summary>
/// Task 13 – Calling a Complex Extension Method using Lambda Expressions [ops]
/// </summary>
public static class LambdaExtensions
{
    //This extension method takes in a dictionary and a delegate
    public static List<K> FilterBy<K, V>(
    this Dictionary<K, V> items,
    KeyValueFilter<K, V> filter)
    {
        var result = new List<K>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<K, V> element in items)
        {
            if (filter(element.Key, element.Value))
                result.Add(element.Key);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

its giving following error:

```
Error     1 Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<K,V>' to 'NewLanguageFeatures.KeyValuePair<K,V>'   and

Error  2    'NewLanguageFeatures.KeyValuePair<K,V>' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'NewLanguageFeatures.KeyValuePair<K,V>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

any ideas to reslove?

Comment: Do you have a KeyValuePair defined in your project, in the NewLanguageFeatures namespace?

Comment: I have ***absolutely*** no idea what the question title means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a typo in your code:

```
public delegate bool KeyValuePair<K, V>(K key, V value);
```

should surely be

```
public delegate bool KeyValueFilter<K, V>(K key, V value);
```

and then it works.

However, a `Func<K,V,bool>` would do the same thing, without needing the extra definition. Finally, using `var` (i.e. `foreach(var element in items)` would have avoided one of the conflicts.

To be honest, though, the existing `Where` does *so much* of this that I wouldn't bother defining this - i.e.

```
var filtered = existing.Where(pair => pair.Key == pair.Value);
           // ^^^ just a random filter to show usage; nothing significant here
```